# How to import an existing project on Magento 1.7 to my local workspace?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have tried to import an existing project on magento 1.7 to my server, i've copied the existing directories into my htdocs folder of my xampp server and also i import the .sql file of the server database on my local xampp.

My problem is that i can access into the admin of magento through localhost and i can login but i cannot see any of the pages that exist on the existing project on the magento interface, i need to modify an existing page but i can't see it, so i can't modify it.

Can anyone help me with this?

Could it be that i need to change some configuration file or something?

Answer (score 0):

**The steps for taking the full backup of the site**

1. Take the backup from the admin module System->tools->backup
   there are 3 backups full system , database and media, only database

   Takefull backup and  download it and extract it in our new folder directory for new site .
2. the sql file of the database  goes in root directory inside var, then unextract it and import it using phpmyadmin or command line in  a new database. its file size will be about 7 MB
3. go to root directory inside `app/etc/local.xml`

   fill information about your database name and password
4. go in database from phpmyadmin or console

   edit `core_config_data` table row where `path= web/unsecure/base_url` and  `path= web/secure/base_url`, set value = url of root [ example http://localhost/demo/demo/ ]
5. delete the cache and session
   `rm -rf var/cache/*` and 
   check if root/.htaccess file is present.
   See if you are missing any step.

Comment: I have followed all the steps but still i'm not able to see the pages on the dashboard > CMS > Pages section. On core_config_data the url values are correct, and on the root of the project it is the .htaccess. Do i need to change some values on the .htaccess file?

Comment: no you don't need to modify .htaccess file. can you share a screenshot? and give permission to files and folders.